# Filling blob with html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save a list of DOM elements within a file. My problem is what type does a blob variable take DOM elements as?

```
var lstElements = new Array();
lstElements.push(document.getElementById('objectOne'));
lstElements.push(document.getElementById('objectTwo'));
lstElements.push(document.getElementById('objectThree'));
var blob = new Blob(lstElements, {type: 'text/plain'});
```

What should the blob type be for it to read the elements correctly "  *type: 'text/plain'*  "?

Comment: explain your end to end goals in detail and how you consider an array of jQuery objects to be utilized as a list of DOM elements from a file. Are you even familiar what is contained within a jQuery object?

Comment: The DOM elements are to be inserted in the array and further on inside the Blob. what type should the blob take to recognize that the blob is containing an array with DOM elements?

Comment: jQuery object is a lot more than array of DOM elements....how would you use this after? Again... if you are specific about end to end goals...in detail, likely get help but as it stands right now this is far too loose to give assistance to

Comment: Okay, so I will be adding the clicked elements into the array, the array will be inserted into a blob variable to be than saved. Once that is done the file can be re-opened any other time and the blob variable is to be read, so that the elements can be re-clicked.

Comment: what part of elements do you need to save? First..the DOM is not a normal javascript object. How would you ever get this back into javascript to do anythng with it?  Creating json data is one thing. and may or may not be valid here..and is readable in javascript. If you don't know how to save it...certainly don't know how to read it. Still haven't outlined goals

Comment: Ok..I'm done and wish you the best....I think you are trying to save page state...and there are far more conventional ways of doing it...that have been tried and tested

Comment: lstElements.push(document.getElementById('objectOne')); 
lstElements[0].click();

So I got the element and can replicate the click. 

All the element is to be saved, not part of it. 

I need the lstElements to be inserted into a blob variable, so that I can use html5 to save the blob in a file "fileWriter.write(blob)...". When requested, the file can be read and the blob is extracted with  "new FileReader().readAsText(file);" 

I need to know, what should the blob type be, for it to contain the array. 

I really don't know how I can outline the goals more than that.

Comment: read as text....great...but it won't be DOM object anymore, and you won't be able to interact with anyhting in a browser with it... read the MDN docs for File API and try saving it every which way you can. WIll be a complete waste of time since it will be useless bytes in a file after

Comment: What would you suggest than, in order to be able to have the same buttons reclicked when requested?

Comment: suggest you start a new question that states very clearly what your application requirements are... **end to end** and use case. Then include that you considered this approach of saving DOM nodes to file. If you clearly outline how you want interface to work you will get a  far better reception. Personally i don't think you understand enoguh about how brosers and the DOm work.